# Deleting records that are similar with previous one SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a query which fetches me the data that is different compared to the previous row,

A sample code (with table creation and data)

```
create table #temp 
(id int, eid int, name char(10),estid int, ecid int, epid int, etc char(5)  )

insert into #temp values (1,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (2,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (3,1,'a',2,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (4,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (5,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (6,1,'a',1,2,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (7,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (8,1,'a',2,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (9,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (10,1,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (11,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (12,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (13,2,'a',2,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (14,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (15,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (16,2,'a',1,2,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (17,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (18,2,'a',2,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (19,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
insert into #temp values (20,2,'a',1,1,1,'a')
```

I tried with some ways of getting the data as the way that i expected

```
SELECT * INTo #Temp_Final
FROM  #temp
WHERE #temp.%%physloc%%
      NOT IN (SELECT Min(b.%%physloc%%)
              FROM   #temp b
              GROUP BY eid,name,estid,ecid,epid,etc)
         ORDER BY id

SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE id not in (SELECT id FROM #Temp_Final) ORDER BY id
```

But i wasn't getting the result as i expected...

This is how the result needs to be

```
select * from #temp where id in (1,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,13,14,16,17,18,19)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Are `id` guaranteed sequential? Also not sure what you are trying to do with `%%physloc%%` there. It shouldn't be used in production code and doesn't do anything useful for this problem anyway.

Comment: Yes id is guaranteed sequential (its indeed identity(1,1))

Comment: That doesn't guarantee that they are sequential. Gaps in `IDENTITY` columns can appear for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple self-join and appropriate comparison:

```
select t.*
from #temp t left outer join
     #temp tprev
     on t.id = tprev.id + 1
where tprev.id is null or
      t.name <> tprev.name or
      t.estid <> tprev.estid or
      t.ecid <> tprev.ecid or
      t.epid <> tprev.epid or
      t.etc <> tprev.etc;
```

This assumes that the ids are sequential with no gaps.  If the ids are not, you can get the previous id using a correlated subquery or the `lag()` function.

Your title says "delete" but the question seems to just want the list of such rows.  You can phrase this as a `delete` query if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012 ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c09c/1))

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                LAG(eid) OVER (ORDER BY id)   AS prev_eid,
                LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY id)  AS prev_name,
                LAG(estid) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_estid,
                LAG(ecid) OVER (ORDER BY id)  AS prev_ecid,
                LAG(epid) OVER (ORDER BY id)  AS prev_epid,
                LAG(etc) OVER (ORDER BY id)   AS prev_etc
         FROM   #temp)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT eid,
                      name,
                      estid,
                      ecid,
                      epid,
                      etc
               INTERSECT
               SELECT prev_eid,
                      prev_name,
                      prev_estid,
                      prev_ecid,
                      prev_epid,
                      prev_etc)
```

Comment: Ah LAG() is a good one. If it is available it beats the self join solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select
    t.id,
    t.eid,
    t.name,
    t.estid,
    t.ecid,
    t.epid,
    t.etc
from #temp t
    left join #temp d
        on  d.id = t.id-1
        and d.eid = t.eid
        and d.name = t.name
        and d.estid = t.estid
        and d.ecid = t.ecid
        and d.epid = t.epid
        and d.etc = t.etc
where d.id is null
```